# Facing error while storing date in a Jemeter variable using beanshell preprocessor

Tags: date, jmeter, beanshell

I am new to Jmeter and I am facing this issue.
The some_date has date like

```
2022-06-5T10:10:10.12345
```

After splitting, 
The final_date has only

```
2022-06-5
```

```
String a = vars.get("some_date");
String b = a.split("T");
log.info(b[0]);
final_date = b[0];
vars.putObject("final_sending_date",final_date);
log.info(final_sending_date);
```

I am getting an error while using vars.putObject

```
javax.script.ScritException: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException : No such property :
final_sending_date for class : Script
```

Comment: typo `log.info(final_date)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a couple of problems with your script:

1. [String.split()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)) function returns an **array** of Strings so you need to change second line to:

   ```
   String [] b = a.split("T");
   ```
2. The `final_sending_date` object is not declared anywhere, most probably you meant something like:

   ```
   log.info(vars.getObject("final_sending_date"));
   ```
3. [Since JMeter 3.1 it's recommended to use JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language for scripting](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/is-beanshell-dead) for maximum performance so consider migrating, the same code will work fine without changes in Groovy

Full code just in case:

```
String a = vars.get("some_date");
String [] b = a.split("T");
log.info(b[0]);
final_date = b[0];
vars.putObject("final_sending_date",final_date);
log.info(vars.getObject("final_sending_date"));
```

Comment: It worked :) Thanks a lot. I have been trying to figure it out for the past couple of hours.